# Convert string to uppercase which are not part of any special charcters

Tags: .net, regex

Need regex that will identify the part of the strings which are enclosed in any special characters and convert the rest in Uppercase. For example,

```
He did soME "experimenting (chemistry, biology)" in (hIS) ScHool Days.
```

Output:

```
HE DID SOME "experimenting (chemistry, biology)" IN (hIS) SCHOOL DAYS.
```

In the example above words enclosed within any special characters remain same while which are not got converted into Uppercase.

Language preferred is VB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([^("]*)((?:(")|(\())(?:(?!(?(3)"|\))).)*.)?
```

Contents of group 1 need to be uppercased, contents of group 2 should be left as they are.

Note that this pattern works with nested groups like `"a(b)c"` but not with overlapping groups like `"a(b"c)`.